# Thinking sphinx - allow null and OR Logic with attribute filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have such index:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :service, with: :active_record do
  # ...
  has currency, as: :currency_attr
end
```

I need to be able to search by currency and also allow null values. So I try this solution (via [official docs](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/common_issues.html#or_attributes)):

```
with_null_currency = "*, IF(currency = 1 OR currency IS NULL) AS my_currency"
Service.search('', :select => with_null_currency, :with  => {'my_currency' => 1})
```

But it doesn't work somehow:

```
  Sphinx Query (7.1ms)  SELECT *, IF(currency = 1 OR currency IS NULL) AS my_currency FROM `service_core` WHERE `my_currency` = 1 AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 20 OPTION max_matches=500000
ThinkingSphinx::SyntaxError: sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting ')' or ',' near 'IS NULL) AS my_currency FROM `service_core` WHERE `my_currency` = 1 AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 20 OPTION max_matches=500000; SHOW META' - SELECT *, IF(currency = 1 OR currency IS NULL) AS my_currency FROM `service_core` WHERE `my_currency` = 1 AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 20 OPTION max_matches=500000; SHOW META
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:91:in `rescue in query'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:94:in `query'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:75:in `query_all'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/search/batch_inquirer.rb:17:in `block in results'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:37:in `block in take'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/innertube-1.1.0/lib/innertube.rb:138:in `take'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:35:in `take'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/search/batch_inquirer.rb:16:in `results'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/middlewares/inquirer.rb:9:in `block in call'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/logger.rb:3:in `log'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/middlewares/inquirer.rb:8:in `call'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/middlewares/geographer.rb:11:in `call'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/middlewares/sphinxql.rb:14:in `call'
... 6 levels...
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/serj/Projects/gearup/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@gearup/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/serj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

How can I make it work?

P.S. I use gem `thinking-sphinx 3.1.1`, `Sphinx 2.1.4-release (rel21-r4421)`, PostgreSQL and `Rails 4.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank Pat for his help. The problem was that I am using alias in my index definition. That is why such error appeared. So, to solve this problem I need to use this line of code:

```
with_null_currency = "*, IF(currency_attr = 1 OR currency_attr = 0, 1, 0) as my_currency"
Service.search('', select: with_null_currency, with: {my_currency: 1})
```

Pat updated the docs to mention this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing wrong IF in sql query write it like this:

```
with_null_currency = "*, IF(currency = 1 OR currency IS NULL, 1, 0) AS my_currency"
```

OR

```
with_null_currency = "*, IF(currency = 1 OR currency IS NULL, true, false) AS my_currency"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. For your first example error: `ThinkingSphinx::SyntaxError: sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting ')' or ',' near 'IS NULL, 1, 0)`. And for the second one error is `ThinkingSphinx::SyntaxError: sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting ')' or ',' near 'IS NULL, true, false)`.

Comment: what would be the error after changing it to above condition?

Comment: The thing is that I have error event when I try `with_null_currency = "*, IF(currency = 1) AS my_currency"`, error is `ThinkingSphinx::ParseError: index service_core: parse error: Sphinx expr: syntax error, unexpected TOK_IDENT near 'currency = 1)'`.

Comment: You have to specify return values in case of condition. I have tested this on select query on console it's working

Comment: I am on Rails 4.1, maybe it's a bug? And I don't understand what you means when you say `You have to specify return values in case of condition`. I create variable with condition (with_null_currency) and then I just call search, by specifying select and with:  `Service.search('', :select => with_null_currency, :with  => {'my_currency' => 1})`

Comment: when you specify IF() in sql you have to specify three parameters first is condition second for true case and third for false case

Comment: Ok, now I got you. It still doesn't work, probably something is wrong with Rails 4.1 and Thinking sphinx.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that what you're writing is not SQL, but SphinxQL - similar, but not identical. Also, NULL doesn't exist as a concept for Sphinx - it translates NULLs when indexing to either blank strings (for fields) or 0 (for integers, timestamps, floats, booleans).

Also, Ahmad's suggestion about three arguments for IF [is correct](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.1.8.html#expr-func-if), which means the SELECT clause ends up looking something like this:

```
with_null_currency = "*, IF(currency = 1 OR currency = 0, 1, 0) as my_currency"
```

Now, this may not be the correct behaviour for what you're actually after, but perhaps the Sphinx index structure needs to be adjusted.